# Length of feature names mismatches the actual size of input X when using sklearn ColumnTransformer

Tags: scikit-learn, pipeline, data-preprocessing

I have designed the following pipelines to train my models:

```
from sklearn.compose import make_column_selector as selector
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

cat_imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy='constant',fill_value='missing')
num_imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy='constant',fill_value=0,add_indicator=True)

categorical_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('imputer',cat_imputer),
    ('encoder',OneHotEncoder())
])

numerical_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('imputer',num_imputer)
])

def get_column_types(X):
    numerical_columns = numerical_columns_selector(X)
    categorical_columns = categorical_columns_selector(X)
    return numerical_columns, categorical_columns

def get_transformer(X,y):
    numerical_columns, categorical_columns = get_column_types(X)
    pre_transformer = ColumnTransformer([
        ('cat_pipe', pre_categorical_pipeline, categorical_columns),
        ('num_pipe', pre_numerical_pipeline, numerical_columns)
        ])
    return transformer
```

When I fit the transformer on my data I get an inconsistency in the nubmer of features when I extract the names, this code is as follows:

```
transformer = models_and_pipelines.get_transformer(X,y)
X = transformer.fit_transform(X)

# this extracts the feature names. I also used an alternive function listed below which yields the same results
starting_features = list(transformer.transformers_[0][1]['encoder'].get_feature_names()) +  list(transformer.transformers_[1][2])

print(X.shape[1])
print(len(starting_features)
```

With the following output:

```
1094
1090
```

Where does this inconsistency in the number of feature names come from?

other links: [function to extract feature names](https://johaupt.github.io/blog/columnTransformer_feature_names.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using v1.1, `get_feature_names_out` is fully fleshed out, so you won't need the manual approach you're trying or the one from your link.

It's possible some of your columns were all-missing? From the docs for `SimpleImputer` (which I guess is what your `num_imputer` is?):

> **Notes**
>
> Columns which only contained missing values at `fit` are discarded upon `transform` if strategy is not `"constant"`.

Comment: upon adding the imputers to the question I noticed that I had add_indicator = true added to the simpleimputer. Disabling this fixed the problem, this makes sense as the manual method of extracting feature names didn't take this option into account.